# Injectivity of a compact self-adjoint operator on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, self-adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be an Hilbert space. Let $F$ be a compact self-adjoint operator on $H$. Show that if $F$ is injective then $H$ is at most countable-dimensional.

I'm not sure how to start this problem...

Below are the definitions I've written down. But I'm not sure how to put the information we have to reach to a conclusion that $H$ is at most countable.

If $F$ is compact, for every bounded sequence $(x_n)$, there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $F((x_{n_k}))$ converges.

Since $F$ is self-adjoint then $\langle F(x), y\rangle = \langle x, F(y)\rangle$.

Since $F$ is injective, for every $y \in Im(F) $, there exists an unique $y$ such that $F(x)=y$.

Any ideas or hints will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the spectral theorem for compact self-adjoint operators?

Comment: Yes! By the spectral theorem, we know that  the set of nonzero eigenvalues of $H$ is at most countable. But what does the eigenvalues of $H$ tell us about the dimension of $H$?

Comment: You also know that $N(F)^{\perp} = \overline{\text{span}\{\phi_1,\phi_2,\cdots\}}$ where $\{\phi_i\}_{i\in \mathbb N}$ is an orthonormal set. But $F$ is compact injective so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F(x)=\sum \lambda_n \langle x, e_n \rangle e_n$ for some orthonormal sequence $(e_n)$. If $x$ is orthogonal to each $e_n$ then $F(x)=0$ so $x=0$ by injectivity. Hence $H$ is the closed subspace spanned by $\{e_1,e_2,...\}$.

Comment: Is $F(x)= \sum \lambda_n \langle x ,e_n \rangle e_n$ from the spectral theorem? But by the spectral theorem, we have $F= \sum \lambda_n P_{\lambda_n}$, where $P_{\lambda_n}$  is the orthogonal projection onto the corresponding eigenspace. How did we get $ \langle x ,e_n \rangle e_n$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @cciirrcclllee For each $n$ take an orthonormal basis for the eigen space of $\lambda_n$ and put these together to get $(e_i)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Could you explain why we are only interested in $x$ orthogonal to each $e_n$?

Comment: A subspace $M$ of a Hilbert space $H$ is dense if and only if the only vector $x$ orthogonal to each element of $M$ is $0$. Take $M$ to be the subspace spanned by the $e_n$'s. @John

Comment: Why is it sufficient to prove that $M$ is dense in order to conclude (in this case) that $M = H$?

Comment: The closed subspace generated by $(e_n)$ is $H$. This implies that $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal basis for $H$. So $H$ has countable orthonormal dimension. You are not trying to prove that $H$ is a countable set. No Hilbert space other than $\{0\}$ can ever be a countable set. You are asked to prove the existence of  a countable orthonormal basis.  @John

Comment: I see. One last question: why is the subspace generated by the $e_i$ closed?

Comment: It is not closed. It is dense which means its closure is equal to $H$. @John

Comment: But then how do we conclude that the dimension of $H$ is countable? Is the dimension of a dense subspace the same as the dimension of its closure?

Comment: Dimension of a Hilbert space is defined as the cardinality of any orthonormal basis. I have proved that $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal basis. @John